# How do I extract a query parameter from a REST path?

Tags: hibernate, rest

I am using hibernate and a REST service. Looking at the code below **REST SERVICE**, how do I extract content_id in this case using a HQL statement (Hibernate query) ?

e.g  My attempt...

```
<query cache-mode="get" cacheable="true" flush-mode="auto"
name="Languages.getLanguageById" read-only="true">
select languageId  as id,displayName as name from Languages where id=<query-param name="languageId" type="java.lang.Long"/>
</query>
```

// **REST SERVICE**

```
@Path("{resource}/getLanguageById")

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
public String getLanguageById(@PathParam("resource") String id, 
                              @QueryParam("content-id")String content_id)
{

            ........
            .......

}
```

//Hibernate XML

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class catalog="CONTENT" name="test.db.com.Languages" table="languages">
  <id name="languageId" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="languageId"/>
   <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="language" type="string">
   <column length="50" name="language" not-null="true"/>
  </property>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="displayName" type="string">
   <column length="50" name="displayName" not-null="true"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found an alternate solution

```
public static List listObject1(String queryname,Long content_id) {
        String query = "select languageId  as id,displayName as name from Languages where id =:query_id";
        Transaction tx = null;    

        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession();
        Query myquery = session.createQuery(query);
        myquery.setParameter("query_id",content_id);

......

.......more code
    }
```